# String to Date conversion using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have string value '05-Jan-18' to be converted to date format using javascript. can someone help me on this.

Comment: You can use [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/) or other libraries if you are lazy. Or do some worthy research utilizing javascript's `Date` API

Comment: `var date = new Date(str_val);`

Answer (score -2):

You can just do:

```
var d = new Date("05-Jan-18")
```

Yeah '05-Jan-18' does not work everywhere. However

```
new Date("05-Jan-18".replace(new RegExp('-', 'g'), ' '))
```

should work

Comment: The Date construct uses `Date.parse()` which is heavily discouraged at this moment (well, if you use it with non-ISO 8601 format like this one). It is not so reliable if I am talking from my experience. It is better to parse the string yourself or use known libraries.

Comment: Not a good idea.. :(   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date   Even if the date was an ISO 8601 format, due to browsers inconsisteancies even that could go wrong.